# Flutter firestore fetch documents with a condition on a map field

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a document in this form:

```
Field:
    NestedField: Value
```

How can I use the `where()` method in Flutter to fetch all documents that satisfy a condition on `NestedField`? I.e:

```
Firestore.collection("forms").where("Field.NestedField",isEqualsTo: "Op1").getDocuments(). // This returns null
```

Comment: What exactly are Field and NestedField?  I'm having a hard time visualizing what your document actually looks like.  A screenshot might help.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for your concern and response. I actually found out what the problem was and I posted it, it was entirely unrelated to how Firestore works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so this was caused by another error with no relation to Firestore directly. The `Field.NesterForm` approach works and it returns the data. Since Firestore uses JSON then it's the correct way to access nested fields this way. The code I was testing with was:

```
List<DocumentSnapshot> docs;
await Firestore.instance.collection('form')
..where("FirstForm.Operator",isEqualTo: _filter.text)
.getDocuments().then((query) {
    docs = query.documents;
});
print("DOCS: $docs");
```

The `..` before the `where()` that I didn't see at first caused the `await`to not actually wait for the return so the print of my docs variable always returned null. Once I removed one dot, it works fine now and the equals is working.